# Using regex in htaccess to 410 status spammy URLs

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url

I'm trying to set up some rules in the htaccess file to combat some spammy incoming links to our site. For example, some spam sites out there are linking to our site in the following way:

```
//www.oursite.com/buy-cheap-medication/
//www.oursite.com/get-medication-now/
//www.oursite.com/buy-medication-online/
```

etc. etc. These incoming links generate a 404 status by our server as the URLs don't actually exist and display the custom 404 page. I could create individual rules for each bad incoming link but there are thousands of them! You will notice that each spammy link contains the word 'medication'.

Can a regex based rule be added to the htaccess file that would watch for any URL containing the word 'medication' and assign it a 410 status? If necessary, I can create a 410 page using:

```
ErrorDocument 410 /410.php
```

The regex based rule would forward and URLs containing the matched word to this custom page WITH the 410 status. I'm unsure of the exact syntax but here is what I have tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^medication$ [L,R=410]
ErrorDocument 410 /410.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule medication - [NC,G]
ErrorDocument 410 /410.php
```

`!` is for NOT (if you test link without the word)
`^` is for begin and `$` for end. No need to test that becaus the word is anyplace in the link

Comment: So far your example is not working. I added the following to the htacess:

# BEGIN Catchall
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule medication - [NC,L,R=410]
</IfModule>
# END Catchall

I omitted the RewriteEngine on as it was already declared earlier in the htaccess.

Comment: If it's still not working, add all your htaccess with [edit]

Comment: Ok, its half working now after the [NC,G] modification. The issue that remains is HTTPS. This is a Wordpress site that uses the HTTPS redirect plugin ... which 301 redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS. If the incoming URL is HTTP then it 301s the URL to 410.php with a 200OK status. If the incoming URL is HTTPS then no redirect happens with a status of 410 Gone. ANy idea how HTTP traffic will also return a 410 status?

Comment: I should also note that the HTTPS redirect script in the htaccess FOLLOWS your script. When I put the HTTPS redirect script BEFORE yours then it 301s the request to HTTPS then returns a 410 status after the redirect.

Comment: Also when the URL is HTTPS, the URL remains the same: '/whatever-mediaction/' and the page renders the content of 410.php. When the URL is HTTP the URL changes from '/whatever-medication/' to 410.php after a 301 redirect.